# Cannot read properties of undefined destructuring from useQuery

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client

If I tried to destructure from apollo's useQuery like so

```
const { loading, data: { getPosts: posts }, err } = useQuery(FETCH_POSTS_QUERY);
```

I get an `Cannot read properties of undefined` error.
I made a workaround, I checked if the data is fetched before I destructe it like so

```
function blog(){
const { loading, data, err } = useQuery(FETCH_POSTS_QUERY);
    let posts = {}
    if (data) {
        posts = data.getPosts;
    }
    // Next line because it prints the empty object
    if (posts.length > 1) {
        return '//someCode'
    } else return '//AnotherCode'
}
export default blog
```

But I find this workaround so tedious I can't live with it.
I also did the same awful workaround in another component because when I map than I pass `post` to it, and because it passes as an undefined first, I have also check if its has data before I destructure `post` in the other component.
Is there anything I do wrong?, because I am following a youtube tutorial and I did the same as the instructor did but I keep getting this annoying error

Answer (score 0):

The [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) operator works better than destructuring here
`const posts = data?.getPosts;`
And then when checking the length of posts
`if (posts?.length > 1) { //do something }`

Comment: The problem is that destructuring is not working is the first place, if it works, I think I don't need to check `posts?.length > 1`

Answer (score 0):

You need to set default value upon your destructing, I think that this will resolve your problem :

```js
const { loading, data: { getPosts: posts }, err } = useQuery(FETCH_POSTS_QUERY);
```

check out this issue for more informations : https://github.com/apollographql/react-apollo/issues/3323